# How to make an ANTLR 3 work in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, antlr3

Can someone instruct me step by step how to install ANTLR 3 in VS2010, then add grammar to a project so it will generate lexer and parser every time I make a change to a project?

Comment: @BartKiers, none of them are up to date, based on my recent weeks of experience. I plan to write a long blog post to cover the details, but not yet find time.

Comment: @LexLi, I see. Removed the links. Thanks.

Comment: @BartKiers, I started to write posts on how to use ANTLR 3 on .NET, so updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This is a recommended VS addon by others, but I am using Visual Studio 11, so I did not try it out myself,

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f

The approach I used for my open source project (http://code.google.com/p/sharpsnmplib/source/detail?r=aab9a1e314a3e9044047f9bee663c2e89952c142) is using the MSBuild target file, (if you are familiar with MSBuild, you can use this).

http://www.antlr.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2009-November/036594.html

Update: I personally wrote some posts about how to use ANTLR on C#/.NET,

http://lextm.com/search/label/ANTLR,

which can help you get started quickly.